# regex in JS for no letters and identical chars

Tags: javascript, regex

got a problem with two regular expressions in javascript.
I need one expression that matches, when my string contains no `a-zA-Z`. Like `12345`.
Stuff like `\W\S` or `[^a-zA-Z]` is not working, cause it matches `123a` etc.
Getting crazy with that one.

The other expression is the matching of two identical letters like the `'ss'` in password.
`(.)\1` is not working with javascript. In c# no problem. What am I doing wrong with that one?

Made a section in my web.config which defines password-rules and in my code (c#, asp.net 3.5) I am reading the rules to create javascript for the client.

Thanks for help

Comment: `(.)\1` works for me to find two consecutive matching characters. ...`/(.)\1/.test("password"); // true` ... `/(.)\1/.test("pasword"); // false`

Comment: @cookiemonster I stand corrected.

Comment: You might want to use /[^a-zA-Z]+/

Comment: Any example for me? Does this one need new Regex or does it work with .match(...) for you? Ah, OK. With new Regex. Wanted to use match only. Seems I have to rewrite my serverside-part from match to new Regex. In c# I iterate over all rules and handle all the same. Any other way instead of using .test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use start and end anchors also like this to make sure your complete string doesn't match any letters:

```
/^[^a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Comment: Ahhh,of course. I was close. My other rule is for empty string ^$.

Comment: Or just `/[a-z]/i` and negate the result.

Comment: @Sardoan: To match empty string just change `+` to `*` in the regex. So make it `/^[^a-zA-Z]*$/`

Comment: I need for every rule one expression. In my webconfig I also define the name of the resource-name. So empty string has an own message-text and no letter has an other message. Over 20 culters defined. It is for a system with over 440.000 logins per day.

Comment: Ok that's fine then keep it separate. Also `(.)\1` should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will work to match consecutive identical characters -

```
(\w)\1{1,}
```

Comment: 12a3567a matches with (\w)\1{1,} only 1234567aa should match

Comment: 12a3567a does not match with (\w)\1{1,} ... I tested the regex here - http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: I tested my regular expressions too online and with c#. They worked. But now they fail beeing rendered in javascript. Got my test-project open and I try everything that gets posted ;)

Comment: I solved my problem with switching from match to test. I think my main problem was using string for the regex, like ...match("..") instead of (/../). That was new to me. Thanks for the help :) (I used my (.)\1)